# Missing byte in CRC in COM port communication

Tags: c#, port, crc

I'm communicating via COM port with a dispenser.

It sends `DLE-STX-DATA-DLE-ETX-CRC`. If 2-byte CRC is different I respond with `NAK` otherwise with `ACK`. So far so good. But what if byte in 2-byte CRC is missing. What can I do then? It contains two-bytes as well.

For example expected CRC was `0x11 0x31`, but it returned `0x31 0x10` (where 0x10 is already part of `DLE-STX-DATA-DLE-ETX-CRC` it tries to return, even without me sending `NAK`!).

What can I do about missing byte in CRC itself?

How to recover?

**Expected behavior**:

- device: `DLE-STX-DATA-DLE-ETX-CRC1-CRC2`
- CRC mismatch
- me: `NAK`
- device: `DLE-STX-DATA-DLE-ETX-CRC1-CRC2`

**Actual behavior**:

- device: `DLE-STX-DATA-DLE-ETX-(missing byte)-CRC2-DLE`
- CRC mismatch
- me: `NAK`
- device: `STX-DATA-DLE-ETX-CRC1-CRC2`

Comment: Can you check the datatype of the response storage?  Unsigned vs Signed int?

Comment: Does the sender repeat the message if you send NAK? Then send a NAK. If not, the protocol is not well designed (e.g. there sould be a length field). A work-around could be to analyse the bytes around the boundary of the pakets and do some guessing.

Comment: Everything operates via unsigned Byte or Byte[].

Comment: It returns DLE-STX-DATA-DLE-ETX part correctly, but one byte is missing in CRC. According to log the CRC already contains 0x31 0x10 (where 0x10 is already DLE response being resent). I then send NAK because 0x31 0x10 is not expected 0x11 0x31 CRC and the response starts with STX instead of DLE, because it was already send in CRC.

Comment: Does your protocol have some sort of byte stuffing or escaping to allow `DLE` items to appear within messages?

Comment: As far as I know.. it doesn't. That last DLE is just message being resend (it continues with being resend). But it is resent BEFORE I even call NAK. I'm clueless as to why. It's like dispenser knows it didn't send the CRC correctly and it is already re-sending the message without even waiting for ACK or NAK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is unsolvable. Even the official Fujitsu utility can't handle this scenario. Even if handled the COM port becomes unusable and computer restart is necessary. You can only fail gracefully from this error.